# Pandas Dataframe: Update values in a certain columns for last n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the example below, I want to update column C for the last 3 rows to the value 0.

Source Dataframe

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Target Dataframe

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 0 3 3
4 4 0 4 4
5 5 0 5 5
```

I tried something like

```
df.tail(3)['C']=0
```

but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: `df.tail` returns a new data frame, so you are changing a copy and not the original one. Use `loc` or `iloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can settle for

```
df.loc[df.tail(3).index, 'C'] = 0
```

Comment: This is the shortest and cleanest result. Thanks.

Comment: `df.loc[df.index[-3:],'C'] = 0` I think is a little quicker.  No need for tail the entire dataframe just slice the index for the last three elements and use loc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.iloc[-3:]['C'] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  0  3  3
3  4  4  0  4  4
4  5  5  0  5  5
```

Other way:

```
df[-3:]['C'] = 0
```

Comment: Error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

Comment: Okay, it is not giving such error on my end. Just updated my answer with one new way. Try to check this.